# "Server not found error " while making HTTPS call from wp7

Tags: windows, web-services, windows-phone-7, ssl, https

I am getting "Server Not found error" while calling Https(SSL) php page. The page is not getting loaded from Wp7 browser giving error as Error loading page, do you want to continue. What are the ways I can by pass the error in WP7 code. The site can be viewed in Desktop

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: could you please post some code to provide some context.

Comment: You likely do not have a valid SSL cert. You need to import the .cer file to get around this, or get a valid certificate. (as your app would be unusable for users without the .cer installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say it works on the desktop without any issue, the root CA for the certificate is likely not one supported by the phone.
Find out what it is and then compare with the details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521150(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: Hi Matt,Thanks for your Answer. We have  "VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3" certificate which is not in the List of root certificates that are pre-installed on a Windows Phone. Is there any other way I can make this certificate trusted on WP7 and that too for all the WP7 that install this App.